# Typescript how to infer type from a constant property value

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, typeof

I want to get the type of a property from a constant previously defined.

```typescript
const my_constant = {
    user: {
        props: {
            name: {
                type: 'string'
            }
        }
    },
    media: {
        props: {
            id: {
                type: 'number'
            }
        }
    }
} as const;

type Name = keyof typeof my_constant;

type Constructed<T extends Name> = {
    [K in keyof typeof my_constant[T]['props']]: typeof my_constant[T]['props'][K]['type']

                                     // ~~~ Type '"type"' cannot be used to index type ...
}
```

I don't understand why I cannot use "type" as index but I can use "props".

If typescript can infer that there is always "props" attribute why it cannot infer that there is always "type"?

Is there another way maybe to get the type?

What I want to achieve is something like this:

```typescript
const user:Constructed<'user'> = {
    name: 'John'
}

const media:Constructed<'media'> = {
    id: 123
}

const user2:Constructed<'user'> = {
    name: 444
    // ~~~ Error
}

const media2:Constructed<'media'> = {
    id: 'something'
    // ~~~ Error
}
```

Here is the playground link with the exact error:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPqklAhmWBeGBvAKBmJgFcIBTAJwC58iTGAHKkJiOwx7ksdOCpwY8RMKAiaCYAcmhUAlmADm04aJgBfNYy06ANGoEATeeiGiWbDvXUl5R87e7jJdaWFJwARtVVPN2iS6QQQaMOgQMKjQANwEBC4UMABy-Em4ANYUCCAAZmISFHnwyNEYWHEJhTAAwuBypMBQFEYAPAAqMBQAHs1gRpGpAgB8MLhcJADaANIwijBZOfmJxYgo9eVQk+0AupPSluzSOzt0K-lrZZhbu-uHEMcze9KJx6FAA)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is actually possible. The typing doesn't exist on runtime (which in which the `const` is ran).

Comment: If you follow the playground link you can see that I can have the type "user" and "media" easily and also I can the "props" object type. I don't see why I cannot go one level down.

Comment: I also think, that what you want to achieve is, that id has the typescript type 'number'.
You are assigning a type literal.
[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCIQLYHtkG8BQyRyYAngA4QBcyA5CAK4YBG0thxMWWNtzcUWsgA+dfgC9aAbnwBffPgD0igM4QUAdwAWcMCS0o4DMFgRYM5ADYRIyFQwDmDiCrAqAdMgBiWKMlZgkH4MIAAm0K5wYaAOADTIwMhwoeGhSSBYYAZ+EOBQpPhmIK7I4dg06NjIALx4HERklDQAzPHKGljgyB1QANbxKqBI+iiNKFgwI8gAbnCWDKMUKMAqyBl69EysgvXIXDx0AEzs8oWdJWVYhxWYOLW4yMpZKwmrs5bAobtjvIwsbLFdvteBITgoxmgashehBSBMSEt4ZdDjJrHo4FRUFDDo9FKEsC41plur5evg0f5MVDaGN2BSEFTarR9ux8EA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript cannot use a string to index the constant. It needs the proper key.
You can check if the object has the attribute `type` and also maybe use a Mapped type to get the real type instead of just "string".

```typescript
const my_constant = {
    user: {
        props: {
            name: {
                type: 'string'
            }
        }
    },
    media: {
        props: {
            id: {
                type: 'number'
            }
        }
    }
} as const;

type Name = keyof typeof my_constant;

type InferType<T> = T extends {type: infer I} ? I : never;

interface Mapped {
    string: string;
    number: number;
}

type Constructed<T extends Name> = {
    [K in keyof typeof my_constant[T]['props']]: 
        InferType<typeof my_constant[T]['props'][K]> extends keyof Mapped ?
            Mapped[InferType<typeof my_constant[T]['props'][K]>] : never
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=31&pc=2#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPqklAhmWBeGBvAKBmJgFcIBTAJwC58iTGAHKkJiOwx7ksdOCpwY8RMKAiaCYAcmhUAlmADm04aJgBfNYy06ANGoEATeeiGiWbDvXUl5R87e7jJdaWFJwARtVVPN2iS6QQQaMOgQMKjQANwEBC4UMABy-Em4ANYUCCAAZmISFHnwyNEYWHEJhTAAkmC51AAqhQA8jQB8MLiNMBQAHlAUYEaReIl0ig1UtWEA-LUwdGAUAG7UlYqDVLnowEkAsuhMkkY2JHKKSnQXynGMHt7US54+VHFaVZIwAMLgcqTAQZGNq9AZDEYpNKdXBcEgAbQA0jBFDAsjl8oliogUH9ylA4Y0ALpw6SWdjSQmEuiBYh1KbNSQtTH5bFlTD4okkskQCmIwmdfqDYaRNHFQ7HCinWY07jik5wulNVrMko4tDsgnE0mscnEhH8wmLGDLNZUULxAhlMgQWi-NBUAFAlrSci+aFnYh8ARuACCYAQAGUoAplKoPlbyFQAEw0O3-QGS52uqjSd2wz1pOhR82W3HwSWmWO4h0J4HSYymVNdD3IhwwKMGRikUhuMNAA)